# Java Pattern split considering capturing groups

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a string passing a regex, but the split token is just the group 1 of the regex. An example:

Original String = `"paulo\\;Is\\;In;Real;Doubt"`

Array formed using the split = `["paulo\\;Is\\;In", "Real", "Doubt"]`

My first idea was to use as regex: `[^\\\\][;]`  but it obviously did not work.

The output was: `["paulo\\;Is\\;I", "Rea", "Doubt"]` (I am using the `String.split()` method.)

My second idea was to use the `;` as a group: `[^\\\\]([;])`, but I just can't tell the split method to just consider the `group(1)` as a split token.

Comment: what is your expected resulting array?

Comment: @Alex It looks like the desired output is `["paulo", "Is", "In;Real;Doubt"]`

Comment: Sorry... The expecte array is wrong...

Comment: It should be:  ["paulo\;Is\;In", "Real", "Doubt"]

Comment: Can you confirm that your initial string is `paulo\\;Is\\;In;Real;Doubt` and not `paulo\;Is\;In;Real;Doubt` (the second one would be equivalent to `paulo;Is;In;Real;Doubt` and what you ask is not doable...)

Comment: Yeap assylias, you are corrected (just updated)... Sorry about all the mess... =o(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is hard to answer because it is entirely unclear. You say your split token is "just the group 1 of the regex". Group 1 of what regex?

EDIT: Still hard to answer, why don't you clarify?

Anyway, if what you want is "split on ';', but only when it's not escaped with a '\'", then you can use negative lookbehind to get what you want.

Example:

```
"paulo\\;Is\\;In;Real;Doubt".split("(?<!\\\\);");
```

gives

```
[ "paulo\;Is\;In", "Real", "Doubt" ]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry about that. Just corrected the question.

Comment: This lookbehind is just what I wanted. Never understood it before! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Good to hear. You might want to read this for more info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post the answer. I was trying to split on forward slash / that is not escaped with backslash \. This works well in Java:
String[] components = id.split("(?<!\\\\)\\/");

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the expression below is true:

```
("\;").equals(";")
```

So your original string is equal to:

```
"paulo;Is;In;Real;Doubt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to modify your input a little bit as I got errors when

```
String x = "paulo\\;Is\\;In;Real;Doubt";
String[] res = x.split("\\\\;");
```

Answer (score 0):

If escapes can escape anything, you would be better off just finding all with a straight global regex, with a single capture group.

Raw regex:

`(?:(?<=;)|(?<=^))([^;\\]*(?:\\.[^;\\]*)*)(?:;|$)`

expanded:

```
(?:                              // prevent (mitigate) re-capture of last field
   (?<=;)
 | (?<=^)
)

( [^;\\]* (?:\\.[^;\\]*)* )      // Capture the field, grp 1 (can be blank)

(?:                              // The delimiter or end o string                             
   ;
 |
   $
)
```